# Is there any way to send a picture WITH the code in Windows Forms?

Tags: windows-forms-designer

I designed a windows forms, in which to insert a picture, I placed a PictureBox. To insert the picture in the pictureBox, I have to give the path of the image file in the code. But if I run this code in another computer, it does not work; since the path of the picture is saved in my computer.

So is there any way to export the picture along with the code?? Like we do in Android Studio, where we save the files to be used in the code project.

Comment: Set the Image property, not the ImageLocation property.  It automatically becomes an embedded resource.

Comment: I want the picture to appear only on certain conditions. If I set the picture in the Image property, in Property window and don't use Image Location, then it is showing always.. But I need it to appear only on certain conditions in the code.

Comment: @AbhilashaGhosh - Please add some code

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to place your pictures in Debug folder of your project solution. If you are using `Image.FromFile()` method so you can just write the name (relative path) of your pictures with extention. Let suppose I have a picture named `dice1.png` residing in my solution's Debug folder (`C:\mySolutionName\myProjectName\bin\Debug`) so I can get`dice1.png` in the program by writing follwing code,

`Image dicePicture = Image.FromFile("dice1.png")`

`pictureBox1.Image = dicePicture;`

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I place in Debug folder, do I have to export the debug folder while using it on another computer??

Comment: Thanks.. It helped a lot

Comment: @AbhilashaGhosh, If my answer helped then please accept it. :) and vote it. This is how it will helps others.